# How do I iterate over a nested JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON object.
Within this object I have an Object array named `'languages'` and in this array there are upwards of 1 languages object listed.

How would I construct a `forEach` loop to access the `'name'` of each `'language'` Object?

Example of what the PHP cURL routine outputs:

```
languages: Array(4)
0: {iso639_1: "en", iso639_2: "eng", name: "English", nativeName: "English"}
1: {iso639_1: "fj", iso639_2: "fij", name: "Fijian", nativeName: "vosa Vakaviti"}
2: {iso639_1: "hi", iso639_2: "hin", name: "Hindi", nativeName: "हिन्दी"}
3: {iso639_1: "ur", iso639_2: "urd", name: "Urdu", nativeName: "اردو"}
length: 4
```

This is how the data is used in a popup rendered dynamically via js:

```
var popupCreateLanguagesResultTD = document.createElement("div");
popupCreateLanguagesResultTD.className = "col";
popupCreateLanguagesResultTD.innerText = result["languages"];
```

What I want it to look like: Languages Spoken: English, Fijian, Hindi, Urdu.

---

Example of JSON file structure:

```
{
  "name": "Canada",
  "topLevelDomain": [
    ".ca"
  ],
  "alpha2Code": "CA",
  "alpha3Code": "CAN",
  "callingCodes": [
    "1"
  ],
  "capital": "Ottawa",
  "altSpellings": [
    "CA"
  ],
  "region": "Americas",
  "subregion": "Northern America",
  "population": 36155487,
  "latlng": [
    60,
    -95
  ],
  "demonym": "Canadian",
  "area": 9984670,
  "gini": 32.6,
  "timezones": [
    "UTC-08:00",
    "UTC-07:00",
    "UTC-06:00",
    "UTC-05:00",
    "UTC-04:00",
    "UTC-03:30"
  ],
  "borders": [
    "USA"
  ],
  "nativeName": "Canada",
  "numericCode": "124",
  "currencies": [
    {
      "code": "CAD",
      "name": "Canadian dollar",
      "symbol": "$"
    }
  ],
  "languages": [
    {
      "iso639_1": "en",
      "iso639_2": "eng",
      "name": "English",
      "nativeName": "English"
    },
    {
      "iso639_1": "fr",
      "iso639_2": "fra",
      "name": "French",
      "nativeName": "français"
    }
  ],
  "translations": {
    "de": "Kanada",
    "es": "Canadá",
    "fr": "Canada",
    "ja": "カナダ",
    "it": "Canada",
    "br": "Canadá",
    "pt": "Canadá",
    "nl": "Canada",
    "hr": "Kanada",
    "fa": "کانادا"
  },
  "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/can.svg",
  "regionalBlocs": [
    {
      "acronym": "NAFTA",
      "name": "North American Free Trade Agreement",
      "otherAcronyms": [],
      "otherNames": [
        "Tratado de Libre Comercio de América del Norte",
        "Accord de Libre-échange Nord-Américain"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cioc": "CAN"
}
```

EDIT: I have tried

```
var popupCreateLanguagesResultTD = document.createElement("div");
popupCreateLanguagesResultTD.className = "col";
result["languages"].forEach(obj => {
         Object.entries(obj).forEach(([name, value]) => {
             popupCreateLanguagesResultTD.innerText = (`${name} ${value}`);
          });
 });
```

But I get `nativeName` and then the native name of the language. e.g French -> `francais`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I forgot to include the various snippets of code I had tried from other StackOverflow Q&As. I've updated my post with the one that I feel most confident with, but I am still not getting the response I'm after. I think the second `.forEach` is what's causing the issue?

Comment: Nothing in your attempt uses `obj.languages` or accesses the `name` property.

Comment: You're iterating over all the properties in the object, not `obj.languages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have data

```
languages: Array(4)
0: {iso639_1: "en", iso639_2: "eng", name: "English", nativeName: "English"}
1: {iso639_1: "fj", iso639_2: "fij", name: "Fijian", nativeName: "vosa Vakaviti"}
2: {iso639_1: "hi", iso639_2: "hin", name: "Hindi", nativeName: "हिन्दी"}
3: {iso639_1: "ur", iso639_2: "urd", name: "Urdu", nativeName: "اردو"}
length: 4
```

and want to output

```
What I want it to look like: Languages Spoken: English, Fijian, Hindi, Urdu.
```

i think you can do

```
const langISpeak = languages.map( lang => lang.nativeName).join(', ')
console.log('i speak in : ' + langISpeak)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over all the properties in the object, not the `languages` array.

Use `map()` to extract all the `name` properties from the objects in that array, and `join()` to combine them into a comma-separated string.

```
popupCreateLanguagesResultTD.innerText = obj.languages.map(lang => lang.name).join(", ");
```